# before changing the value: `.html('usa')` print it

Tags: jquery, html

One of the next lines changes the text.. before I change it, I want to check if the text is not equal to 'Active'. how can I do that?

```
if ($(".myimg").parent('p').find(".status").html != 'Active') {

    // change the text
    $(".myimg").parent('p').find(".status").html('Paused'); 

}
```

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.html()` to get the current html

```
var status = $(".myimg").parent('p').find(".status");

if (status.html() != 'Active') {

    // change the text
   status.html('Paused'); 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use this:

```
var status = $(".myimg").parent('p').find(".status");
if (status.html() != 'Active') {
    status.html('Paused'); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".myimg").parent('p').find(".status").html(function(_,txt) {
    return txt == 'Active' ?  'Paused' : txt;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get, or set, the text *use* `text()`:

```
var status = $(".myimg").parent('p').find(".status");

status.text(function(i, t) {
    return t == 'Active' ? 'Paused' : 'Active';
});
```

References:

- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).